# recursively delete all files+folders except a specific one file in solaris

Tags: find, directory, solaris, delete

The below command recursively deletes all but `104.tar` file under `/tmp/CURRENT` folder.

```
find /tmp/CURRENT/ -type f ! -name '104.tar' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

It however, does not recursively delete any sub-folders under `/tmp/CURRENT`.

if I give `-type d` it may help but I don't want a separate command. My requirement is to delete both files and folders with the same single command which I tried below but it did not help.

```
find /tmp/CURRENT/ -type f -type d ! -name '104.tar' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

If I don't specify `-type` option at all, then the command delete the entire `/tmp/CURRENT` folder rather than its contents !

Note: MY OS is Sun Solaris Sparc.

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: Unless you _know_ it is needed, avoid using `rm -f`. You only need `-r` to make it recursive and remove directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `-type f` you are telling `find` to *only* consider files and nothing else. So it's normal that this does not delete directories. To avoid deleting `/tmp/CURRENT/` itself, you could try a few things:

1. If your `find` supports `-mindepth` (GNU `find`—the default on Linux systems—has this, I don't know what other `find` versions might support it), you can tell it to only look at things at least one level down:

   ```
   find /tmp/CURRENT/  ! -name '104.tar' -mindepth 1
   ```
2. Use a second `!` operator to exclude it:

   ```
   find /tmp/CURRENT/ ! -path /tmp/CURRENT/ ! -name '104.tar'
   ```
3. Just use `-path`, and look for paths beginning with `/tmp/CURRENT` and followed by at least one more character:

   ```
   find /tmp/CURRENT/ -path '/tmp/CURRENT/?*' ! -name '104.tar'
   ```

In all three cases, you can add `-exec rm -r {} +` to the end of the command to delete the matches.

However, note that these commands will delete *everything* except the specific file `/tmp/CURRENT/104.tar`. So if you have `/tmp/CURRENT/dir1/104.tar` or any other files named `104.tar` in subdirectories, those will be removed. If this is not what you want, then please edit your question to clarify.

Of course, if all you want is to delete everything in `/tmp/CURRENT` except `/tmp/CURRENT/104.tar`, you don't need `find` at all. You can just run this in bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -r /tmp/CURRENT/!(104.tar)
```

Comment: the second option worked fine !! Thank you